# Ceylon Higher Order Function

Tags: jvm-languages, ceylon

I have the code:

```
shared Integer getInt() {
    return 42;
}

shared Integer() i1() {
    return getInt;
}

shared Callable<Integer,Nothing> i2() {
    return getInt;
}

shared Callable<Integer,[]> i3() {
    return getInt;
}

void run() {
    // OK
    i1()();
    // Illegal `[] is not assignable to Nothing`
    i2()();
    // OK
    i3()();
}
```

I am not sure why the compiler is OK with the "i2" declaration though. Nothing is a subtype of everything and therefore a subtype of the empty tuple, so I can kind of understand why I can do the declaration. But once I've done that it seems impossible for me to invoke "i2" normally as calling it with no arguments, empty tuple, means calling it with a supertype of what it wants which Ceylon rejects.  So is it possible at all to invoke the `getInt` returned from i2?

Answer (score 1):

Lets modify your example a little bit.

```
shared Integer getInt(Integer x) {
    return 42 + x;
}

shared Integer(Integer) i1() {
    return getInt;
}

shared Callable<Integer,Nothing> i2() {
    return getInt;
}

shared Callable<Integer,[Integer]> i3() {
    return getInt;
}
```

As you mentioned `Nothing` is subtype of `[]`, because it's subtype of everything. It is also subtype of `[Integer]`.

Type `Callable<Integer, Nothing>` describes any function that returns `Integer`. However it doesn't say it takes no arguments.

It is possible to call function function returned from `i2`, but you need to typecheck it first:

```
val gi = i2();
if(is Callable<Integer, [Integer, Integer]> gi) {
     gi(1,2);
}
```

Above example is fine, because `[Integer, Integer]` is assignable to `[Integer]` and therefore `Callable<Integer, [Integer]>` is assignable to `Callable<Integer, [Integer, Integer]>`, as the second type parameter of `Callable` is contravariant.

Comment: Hi I'm not sure what you are meaning. Perhaps you are using a different language? `val` is not ceylon, and `[Integer, Integer]` it not assignable to `[Integer]`. Your code compiles but the `if` statement is not entered. Your point seems a bit all over the place, I'm not sure what your point is trying to be.

Answer (score 1):

`Callable<Integer, Nothing>` is legal because the second type argument must satisfy `Anything[]`, which `Nothing` does because, like you said, it's a subtype of every type. But such a function can never be invoked because it's expecting an instance of `Nothing`, and no such instance exists.

You can do `apply(i2(), nothing)`, which makes the type checker happy, but of course that just blows up at run time because `nothing` is a placeholder for something that can't exist.

Comment: Okay, this make sense to me. I read through https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ceylon-users/biVLQTmti-8 which helped me understand more but I'm still a bit confused why ceylon let's me shoot myself in foot using Nothing.

Comment: The compiler warns you if your code contains expressions of type `Nothing`, and your program immediately explodes if an expression of type `Nothing` is encountered at run time. Your feet are safe.

Comment: "but I'm still a bit confused why ceylon let's me shoot myself in foot using Nothing" -- Well you are really not supposed to be using Callable directly, only when you know exactly what you're doing. The alternative (much nicer) syntax without Callable (your `i1()`) is perfectly safe.